# how to build a website supporting multi-language

Tags: multilingual

I am curious how the website www.student.com support multi-language.

1. Do they use google api or other method instead?
2. What's the common way to build a website /app to support multi-language?

Comment: Voting to close this question because it is not about **programming**, but asking for recommendation and information. This is not a bad question, but does not belong on SO.

Comment: yes I agree. but for such questions ,where should I post ?

Answer (score 1):

Every modern browser sends a "Accept-Language"- Header with its preferred languages.

On the server side this can be read and  dynamic redirect to a page with the correct language.

Request-Header: 
Accept-Language: de-de

Server redirects to: 
https://www.student.com/de-de